# No resource files named META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider were found

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I'm a beginner who just started to learn using JPA to connect and manage a MySQL database on a virtual machine but I get this message:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No resource files named META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider were found. Please make sure that the persistence provider jar file is in your classpath.

I've looked almost every post on StackOverflow related to that problem, yet still I couldn't solve it.

In pom.xml, I have these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.9-rc</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence-unit name="Eclipselink_JPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://ip_address:port/jpadb"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

And, this is the code:

```
public class CreateEmployee {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "Eclipselink_JPA" );

    EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
    entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

    Employee employee = new Employee( );
    employee.setEid( 1201 );
    employee.setEname( "Gopal" );
    employee.setSalary( 40000 );
    employee.setDeg( "Technical Manager" );

    entitymanager.persist( employee );
    entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );

    entitymanager.close( );
    emfactory.close( );
}
}
```

Comment: You need to add a JPA implementation on the classpath (eg Hibernate or EclipseLink), currently you only have the API.

Comment: It really worked. Thank you so much.